# Application of the Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

We taken any two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ (both real or both complex) and consider the set $B(X,Y)$ consisting of all bounded linear operators from $X$ into $Y$. 
My question is: if $B(X,Y)$ is Banach then $Y$ is Banach? If this is true, which the idea of the demonstration?

Comment: $B(X,Y)$ is a Banach space if and only if $X = \{0\}$ or $Y$ is a Banach space. If $X \neq \{0\}$, any $\lambda \in X'$ with $\lVert\lambda\rVert = 1$ gives an isometric embedding of $Y$ into $B(X,Y)$ via $y \mapsto (x \mapsto \lambda(x)\cdot y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming furthermore that $X$ and $Y$ are not equal to {$0$}, you can first show that $B(X,Y)$ has a closed subspace which is isometrically isomorphic to $Y$, by setting $T_{\Lambda,y}(x)=\Lambda(x)y$, for $\Lambda \in X^*$, the dual space of $X$ and $y \in Y$. $T_{\Lambda,y} \in B(X,Y)$ with norm $\|\Lambda\|_{X^*}\|y\|_Y$.

Then, if $Y$ is not complete, $B(X,Y)$ is not Banach, which is the contrapositive of the statement you are trying to prove.

If you want more details, I have them, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but if you don`t mind, I would like the details of the prove.